# Unable to subscribe/unsubscribe on kafka topic by command received by REST request

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, zio

I want to write an application designed on ZIO stack completely.
I'm new at this framework, so maybe solution is trivial and I misunderstand something important.
And faced following problem.
I need to unsubscribe from kafka topic with command received by REST.
Also I need to subscribe on topic by REST as well.
I wrote a following code using zio-kafka to describe an effect that subscribes to topic and prints event to console:

```
private val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(List("localhost:9092")).withGroupId("MyConsumerGroup")
    .withOffsetRetrieval(OffsetRetrieval.Auto(AutoOffsetStrategy.Earliest))

private val managedConsumer = Consumer.make(consumerSettings)

val consumer: ZLayer[Clock with Blocking, Throwable, Has[Consumer]] = ZLayer.fromManaged(managedConsumer)

def startStream: ZIO[Console with Any with Has[Consumer] with Clock, Throwable, Unit] =
    Consumer.subscribeAnd(Subscription.topics("myTopic"))
      .plainStream(Serde.string, Serde.string)
      .tap(cr => zio.console.putStrLn(cr.value))
      .map(_.offset)
      .aggregateAsync(Consumer.offsetBatches)
      .run(ZSink.foreach(_.commit))
```

Then I described REST endpoints using zhttp:

```
  private val app = HttpApp.fromEffectFunction{
    case Method.POST -> Root / "stop" => for {
      _ <- ZIO.serviceWith[Consumer](_.unsubscribe)
      _ <- zio.console.putStrLn("stopped")
    } yield Response.ok
    case Method.POST -> Root / "start" => for {
      _ <- startStream.fork
      _ <- zio.console.putStrLn("started")
    } yield Response.ok
  }

private val server = Server.port(8080) ++ Server.app(app)
```

And finally I'm running my simple program with main method:

```
override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = (for {
    _ <- startStream.provideSomeLayer(consumer ++ Console.live).fork
    _ <- server.make.use(_ => console.putStrLn("server started") *> ZIO.never)
      .provideCustomLayer(ServerChannelFactory.auto ++ EventLoopGroup.auto() ++ consumer)
} yield ()).exitCode
```

It runs fine but problem is when I run the program it reacts on `/stop` request but `Consumer` remains subscribed and messages still read from topic.
If I run my program with server effect only like below:

```
override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = 
  server.make.use(_ => console.putStrLn("server started") *> ZIO.never)
    .provideCustomLayer(ServerChannelFactory.auto ++ EventLoopGroup.auto() ++ consumer)
  .exitCode
```

And after I call `/start` endpoint, in console I can see that consumer is alive and I can see some information about kafka cluster but no messages are read from topic.
Please show me where I'm wrong and where is my misunderstanding.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `consumer` layer twice which is effectful. This means the consumer that is unsubscribing is not the same.

What about

```
override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = (for {
    _ <- startStream.fork
    _ <- server.make.use(_ => console.putStrLn("server started") *> ZIO.never)
} yield ()).provideSomeLayer(ServerChannelFactory.auto ++ EventLoopGroup.auto() ++ consumer)
.exitCode
```

note: might not compile, not tested

Comment: Thank you for your answer  
Seems that it was I was looking for...  
Quite stupid mistake  
This is strange but after resubscribing I'm starting to get the same message twice, but probably this is another issue

Comment: wild guess but that might be the consumer closing after reading the last message but before  committing. edit: probably not since you're using unsubscribe

Comment: Seems something wrong with fibers. If everething is implemented by your advice, only one cycle of ```/stop``` - ```/start``` works, after that we can stop consuming but unable to start again. I tryed to ```.join``` ```startStream``` effect and it became stable. But request to ```/start``` endpoint wil never be received cause of consumer blocks the thread

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement this tonight, will keep you up to date.

Comment: Usually the chat options appear after you spam the comments a bit, honestly don't know any other way to open it 